# Find a summary statistics for multiple values

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have written the following `r` code.

```
t = seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1)
for(i in c(t)){
  print(c( i, round(2^i, 3) , round(exp(-3*i),3)))
 
}
```

The outputs are

```
[1] 0.100 1.072 1.000
[1] 0.200 1.149 1.000
[1] 0.300 1.231 0.000
[1] 0.40 1.32 0.00
[1] 0.500 1.414 0.000
[1] 0.600 1.516 0.000
[1] 0.700 1.625 0.000
[1] 0.800 1.741 0.000
[1] 0.900 1.866 0.000
[1] 1 2 0
```

I want to find the `minimum` and the `maximum` values for each column. My question is how to store these outputs in a `data frame`. My intention is to find the `minimum` and the `maximum` value for `i` that corresponds to `2^i` and `exp(-3*i)`.
For example, the above output, the `min(2^i) = 1.072` and the `max(2^i) = 1.866`. Similarly, I want to do it for the second column as well. My actual code would generate `100000` values.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you just want to store `t`, `round(2^t, 3)` and `round(exp(-3 * t))` in a data frame?

But I think you have missed the `digits =`  argument in your second `round` (all values are 0 or 1), so I'll assume you meant to use 3 as in the first.

```
dat <- data.frame(t = seq(0.01, 5, by = 0.001))
dat$a <- round(2^dat$t, 3)
dat$b <- round(exp(-3 * dat$t), 3)
```

And then you can use `min(dat$a)`, `max(dat$a)` *etc*, or even `summary(dat)`.

A tidier way uses `dplyr::mutate` to create all the columns.

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(t = seq(0.01, 5, by = 0.001)) %>% 
  mutate(a = round(2^t, 3),
         b = round(exp(-3 * t), 3))
```

Comment: @jared_mamrot Yes, you need to create at least one column first. Edited my answer. This can be avoided by using `dplyr::mutate` to create columns in one step.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to start from a data frame, which can be constructed by

```
x <- seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1)
df <- data.frame(cbind(x, round(2**x, 3), round(exp(-3 * x), 3)))
```

Then, if you just want to have the `min` and `max` for each column, you can try

```
> Map(range, df)
$x
[1] 0.1 1.0

$V2
[1] 1.072 2.000

$V3
[1] 0.050 0.741
```

Otherwise, a more comprehensive result can be provided by `summary`, e.g.,

```
> summary(df)
       x               V2              V3
 Min.   :0.100   Min.   :1.072   Min.   :0.05000
 1st Qu.:0.325   1st Qu.:1.253   1st Qu.:0.09875
 Median :0.550   Median :1.465   Median :0.19400
 Mean   :0.550   Mean   :1.493   Mean   :0.27160
 3rd Qu.:0.775   3rd Qu.:1.712   3rd Qu.:0.38050
 Max.   :1.000   Max.   :2.000   Max.   :0.74100
```